# Mongoose's push acting weird

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

So I've spent the last 2 days working on this and I am going crazy, here is my code (part of it):

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

    mongoose.connect('',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
})

const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    posts: Array,
    upvotes: Number,
    downvotes: Number,
    fans: Array,
    dmUserWhenUpvoted: Boolean,
    dmUserWhenDownVoted: Boolean
})

const postsModel = mongoose.model("Posts",postsSchema)




    /**
     *
     * @param {Object} user
     */
    async function getPosts(user){
        if(!user) user = message.author

        let posts = await postsModel.findOne({_id: user.id})
        if(posts === null){
            let newData = new postsModel({
                _id: user.id,
                posts: [],
                upvotes: 0,
                downvotes: 0,
                fans: [],
                dmUserWhenUpvoted: false,
                dmUserWhenDownVoted: false
            })

            await newData.save()
            posts = await postsModel.findOne({_id: user.id})
        }

        return {
            _id: user.id,
            posts: posts.posts,
            upvotes: posts.upvotes,
            downvotes: posts.downvotes,
            fans: posts.fans,
            dmUserWhenUpvoted: posts.dmUserWhenUpvoted,
            dmUserWhenDownVoted: posts.dmUserWhenDownVoted,
            account: posts
        }
    }
```

these are the 2 methods i used to push:

```js
                    let getposts = await getPosts()

                    postsModel.updateOne(
                        {_id: message.author.id},
                        {
                          "$push": {
                            "posts": {
                                id: s.id,
                                upvotes: 0,
                                downvotes: 0
                            },
                          }
                        },
                        function(err, response) {
                         console.log(err)
                         console.log(response)
                        }
                      )

                    console.log(getposts.account)
                    await message.delete()
```

this method doesn't push anything when i logged posts.account and the error logs as `null`

method 2:

```js
                    let getposts = await getPosts()

                    getposts.account.posts.push({
                        id: s.id,
                        upvotes: 0,
                        downvotes: 0
                    })

                    await getposts.account.save(function(err){
                      console.log(err)
                    });

                    console.log(getposts.account)
                    await message.delete()
```

when I log getposts.account, it logs the array (posts) with the pushed object inside it, but when i went to my dashboard and viewed my collection, its empty. Hope someone can help me with my problem, this problem `only` occurs to this part of the code, I use method 2 to push all my stuff in different collections and it works

Comment: Can you show exactly what your `posts` path is an array of? So can you get more specific with this: `posts: Array`. mongoose is pretty particular about what you can push into an array depending on what you specific in the schema. It may just be ignoring the pushed docs on save() because they don't fit what it's expecting.

Comment: codemonkey, im sorry but i dont know what u mean. I specified posts as a array, are u saying i should do `posts: []`?

Comment: Here is a typical schema path in mongoose: `posts: [String]`, which tells mongoose that you will be putting an array of strings into that field. It looks like you're pushing an array of objects into it so really your schema should look like this: `posts: [new mongoose.Schema({})]`, which will tell mongoose that it's going to be an array of arbitrary objects.

Comment: aight ill try that

Comment: alright so i tried this:

```js
const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id: String,
 posts: [new mongoose.Schema({})],
 upvotes: Number,
 downvotes: Number,
 fans: Array,
 dmUserWhenUpvoted: Boolean,
 dmUserWhenDownVoted: Boolean
})

const postsModel = mongoose.model("Posts",postsSchema)
```
but now it didnt pushed the object either, it just added some random stuff inside it:

{
  fans: [],
  _id: '715956009327263858',
  posts: [ { _id: 60399ccd4b2d2833e46cdc88 } ],
  upvotes: 0,
  downvotes: 0,
  dmUserWhenUpvoted: false,
  dmUserWhenDownVoted: false,
  __v: 21
}

Comment: That's a different problem. The main thing is you got the schema right. I'll take a look at your code in a few hours when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out you don't actually even need to specify an array of arbitrary mongoose objects with `posts: [new mongoose.Schema({}, {versionKey: false, _id: false})]`. This will get the job done just the same: `posts: Array`, which is what you had originally anyway.

So let's imagine we have just one document in your `Posts` collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6039b9ff08e0c46c9c04f963"),
        "fans" : [ ],
        "posts" : [ ],
        "upvotes" : 0,
        "downvotes" : 0,
        "dmUserWhenUpvoted" : false,
        "dmUserWhenDownVoted" : false,
}
```

As you can see, the `posts` field is empty. To push a new post object into it, you will need this code (or a variation of it):

```
const postsModel = mongoose.model('Posts');

const addPosts = () => {
    postsModel.findOne({_id: '6039b9ff08e0c46c9c04f963'})
        .then(post => {
            post.posts.push({
                id: 'some_id_here',
                upvotes: 0,
                downvotes: 0
            })
            post.save()
        })
}
addPosts()
```

I am more of a `then` guy, but if you prefer `await`ing, it will look like so:

```
const postsModel = mongoose.model('Posts');

const addPosts = async () => {
    const post = await postsModel.findOne({_id: '6039b9ff08e0c46c9c04f963'})
    post.posts.push({
        id: 'some_id_here_1',
        upvotes: 0,
        downvotes: 0
    });

    await post.save();
    return 'ok';
}
addPosts().then(r => console.log(r))
```